# fix InnoDB: corrupted TRX_NO after upgrading to 10.3.31

Tags: mysql, innodb, upgrade, mariadb-10.3

After upgrading mariadb from 10.3.25 to 10.3.31 it fails to start like described in [this bug report](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1823558.html)

I temporary fixed it by downgrading mariadb to 10.3.25 again like I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70088162/1069083).

To fix this completely, it seems I have to

1. `mysqldump -p --all-databases>/tmp/all.sql`
2. delete all tables
3. upgrade mariadb
4. reimport the dump

But that seems like a lot of work and dangerous. Also I get an error while exporting with mysqldump:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT `Vorname`, `Name`, `Stra?e` FROM `adresses`':
  Unknown column 'Stra?e' in 'field list' (1054)
```

There seemed to be a UTF-8 encoding problem. It should be "Straße" with a german sharp "s"
I deleted that very old table and the error is gone.

I could wait a few months and see if a newer version will still produce that error. Is there any hope, they will fix this in a future version? Or is it something corrupt in my current database? Maybe the UTF-8 problem was the cause already?

I will try upgrading again, when I have the time and see if the `corrupted TRX_NO` error is gone too.

I'll keep you updated...

My question:
Is there another way to fix the `corrupted TRX_NO` error than dumping the whole database?

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions in your post, please try to focus on one. Do you want help with dumping your tables with non-ASCII characters in column names? Then provide information about your environment and try to create a reproducible example. Do you want someone to look into their crystal ball and tell you what MariaDB developers will or won't do in the future? That's unlikely to be answered on this site. Is something corrupt? Again, a crystal ball question, at least given the provided details.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue. I used [this link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-deb-files/#executing-add-apt-repository) in order to add a new mariadb repository. Indeed, this repository should contain the mariadb fix and the right mariadb version (for mariadb `10.3.X`).

Here is how I solved this problem (you may need a mysql dump; be sure to have one):

```
    # checking mariadb version before uninstall
    dpkg -l |grep mariadb-server-10|grep ii|xargs|cut -d" " -f3
    cp -rp /etc/mysql /etc/mysql.bck
    cp -rp /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bck
    sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
    release=`lsb_release -c --short`
    distro=`lsb_release -i --short |tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
    sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/$distro $release main"
    sudo apt remove -y mysql-\* mariadb-\* galera-\* libmysqlclient libmariadb3
    sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove
    sudo apt update 2>/dev/null |awk '/NO_PUBKEY/ {print $NF}' |xargs -I{} sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x{}
    sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y mariadb-server
    # checking the new mariadb version
    dpkg -l |grep mariadb-server-10|grep ii|xargs|cut -d" " -f3
    systemctl restart mariadb
    # seems to be ok. Upgrading, restoring, upgrading...
    mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force
    # if it is ok, no need to restore a dump.

    # otherwise
    mysql -uroot -p < /path/to/your/backup
    mysql_upgrade -uroot -p --force
    systemctl restart mariadb
    ps aux |grep -E "mysql|maria"
```

I hope it could help...

Thanks,

Rémy